# How do I time a recursive function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, recursion, timing

I am currently in the works of trying to time a merge sort function.
The only problem is that the merge sort function is recursive and will return the time every time it was completed.

How can I fix this?

```
def MergeSort(argShuffledList):
    dblStart = time.clock()
    if len(argShuffledList)>1:
        intMidValue = len(argShuffledList)//2
        listLeftHalf = argShuffledList[:intMidValue]
        listRightHalf = argShuffledList[intMidValue:]

        left_part = MergeSort(listLeftHalf)
        right_part = MergeSort(listRightHalf)


        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(listLeftHalf) and j < len(listRightHalf):

            if listLeftHalf[i] < listRightHalf[j]:
                argShuffledList[k]=listLeftHalf[i]
                i =i+1

            else:
                argShuffledList[k]=listRightHalf[j]
                j=j+1

            k=k+1

        while i < len(listLeftHalf):
            argShuffledList[k]=listLeftHalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1


        while j < len(listRightHalf):
            argShuffledList[k]=listRightHalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1


    intTime = "%.2f" % ((time.clock() - dblStart) * 1000000)
    message = "Elasped Time: " + str(intTime) + " microseconds"
    print("Selection Sort: ", argShuffledList)
    print(message, "\n")
```

Comment: Why have timing code inside the function? Why not just record the time before calling and after returning?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, exactly. Moreover, one should use the `timeit` module.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried moving the timing outside the method?  In other words, start the timing, then call your method, then stop the timing:

```
# Start timing
dblStart = time.clock()
# Call method
MergeSort(argShuffledList)
# Stop timing and print results
intTime = "%.2f" % ((time.clock() - dblStart) * 1000000)
message = "Elasped Time: " + str(intTime) + " microseconds"
print(message, "\n")
```

Comment: Good example of the naive approach. Using a timing library as juanpa suggested would be a good thing to mention and show the use of. A single timing testike this is entirely useless for any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

here is a custom decorator that I use:

```
def timed(fn):
    # make sure wherever u used this, imports will be ready
    from time import perf_counter
    from functools import wraps
    # wraps preserves the metadata of fn
    @wraps(fn)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        start = perf_counter()
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        end = perf_counter()
        elapsed = end - start
        args_ = [str(a) for a in args]
        kwargs_ = ["{0}={1}".format(k, v) for (k, v) in kwargs.items()]
        all_args = args_ + kwargs_
        args_str = ",".join(all_args)
        print("{0} ({1}) took {2:.6f} to run.".format(fn.__name__, args_str, elapsed))
        return result
    return inner
```

Now define a function that will return the recursive function

```
@timed
def time_recursive(argShuffledList):
    return MergeSort(argShuffledList)
```

call the function:

```
time_recursive([2,3,42,23,-12])
```

I removed this `dblStart = time.clock()` and tested

[image]